# ESS: Disable spaces around `=` in function arguments

Tags: ess, r

With ESS + auto-complete, I get AC suggestions for function arguments that allow me to save time typing them out. What irks me is that it completes the function arguments with spaces around them. For example: `print(x = )` instead of `print(x=)`.

Is there a way to change this behavior in ESS using some variable customization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Features) for a hint to the solution. From the changelist for 12.09-1:

> ESS[R] Auto-completion: new variable ess-ac-R-argument-suffix to
>   customize the insertion of trailing "=". Defaults to “ = “.

And from the documentation for the variable `ess-ac-R-argument-suffix`:

> ess-ac-R-argument-suffix is a variable defined in
>   'ess-r-completion.el'. Its value is " = "
>
> This variable is an alias for 'ess-R-argument-suffix'.   This
>   variable is obsolete since 15.3;   use 'ess-R-argument-suffix'
>   instead.
>
> Documentation: Suffix appended by 'ac-source-R' and `ac-source-R-args'
>   to candidates.
>
> You can customize this variable.

To fix:

`(setq ess-R-argument-suffix "=")`